# Redirect to Page based on Input Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, post-redirect-get

I am attempting to create a form on the page that requires the user to input text. Once the form is submitted, the user will then be redirected to the page assigned to it. My question is where am I going wrong and how should I resolve this issue? Could someone include a JSFiddle or Codepen.io pen for deminstration purposes?

For example:

1. User enters and submits "**123456**"
2. User is then redirected to the page www.domain.com/**123456**

I am assuming it is something like this:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="projectid" maxlength="6">
    <input onclick="findProject()" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function findProject(){
    document.location = document.getElementById('projectId').value();
}
```

I have included my own pen: http://codepen.io/ShaneHicks/pen/eZbbLz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `/` before the url fragment

`document.location = '/' + document.getElementById('projectId').value;`

Comment: I am trying this out. No redirect: http://preview.ieditnetwork.com Am I missing something?

Comment: @ShaneHicks, in html file `type="text id="projectId"` is incorrect. It should be `type="text" id="projectId"`. Also change the input type to `button` from `submit`

Comment: Again, I have replaced both of these but to no avail. Can you include a JSFiddle or Codepen.io pen?

Comment: I made a small mistake. it should be `value` not `value()` in the javascript code.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have saved me much time and energy! As a reward, I have marked this question as solved with your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
    <input id="projectId" maxlength="6">
    <input onclick="return findProject()" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script>
    function findProject(){
        window.location = document.getElementById("projectId").value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```